# VBS: Display message on logon screen

Tags: windows, vbscript, startup

It is possible to set up Windows so that it displays [verbose messages during startup or shutdown](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325376).

I'm writing a VBScript procedure which will be ran at startup and I would like to display a meaning message instead of the default "*Running startup scripts*".

How to achieve this in VBS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Windows administrative tools which allow you to configure start up for specific users or users group to execute anything  on start-up, shutdown even change their backgrounds. Network policy maybe useful for that as well if you are on domain controlled environment.

Also you can use MSCONFIG on a single system to add or define what ever you want to run at startup, for as long as it is valid windows program.

Once you configured what script to run use Windows console (run that under wscript.exe) to execute your VBS file with what ever you want to put there (with wscript you will get dialog with your text in it).
Usually it should look like

```
 Wscript.Echo "Meaningful message goes here"
```

If you run that under cscript.exe you'll get output in your console window.

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for. I'd like to print a message on the Welcome screen.

Comment: @Spack That should be done using Windows Admin tools.There is a special text box for Welcome message which can be shown for individual users or group.